# Can I create own public blockchain in Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain

Is it possible to create own ethereum public network, and use it for my token, created on Solidity?

I want to have cryptocurrency without mining option, which can be traded on markets.

Comment: Cryptocurrency without mining? What consensus also then are you planning to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a Token which is basically a decentral application on top of a blockchain (Ethereum, NEO, Nxt, ... )

Note that this token will not have its own blockchain, but piggy backs on another blockchain in which the smart contract is deployed on.

As an example, you can check out [ERC-20 Token Standard (Ethereum)](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md)

Comment: ok! If i want to give thist tokens/coins to other people all these transaction fees will be on me?

Comment: @user2868337 transaction fees goes to miners of that blockchain. so if you are mining your own fork of ethereum which your token is on, yes. but if the token is on mainnet ethereum, the fee will go to whoever mines the related blocks